# Movable list in CI

Tags: codeigniter

I have to make nested list of items and i have to make theme movable. List is stored in database, user can move items on page and then store it back in database. My solution is to store list in Session class and make jQuery fetch and store in user session, but dunno if it's good. What is the best way to approach this problem in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [jQuery UI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default), and I'd probably set it to send an AJAX call on the `update` event containing the new sort order.